# How to access line number in field code in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

Is there a way to access the current line number on the page in a field code in Microsoft Word?  Similar to access the page number or number of pages as "Page" or "NumPages"?

My use case is to do conditional formatting - to apply different formatting at or toward the bottom of the page.

Comment: If you could number all your lines with a SEQ field, you might be able to do something with an IF field. You can’t access actual line numbers via field coding.

Comment: I do not find the field code about line number in [List of field codes in Word](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/list-of-field-codes-in-word-1ad6d91a-55a7-4a8d-b535-cf7888659a51),